# How do Russian speakers commonly express the idea of "a powder-keg situation"?

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I just said:

> Обе стороны на грани. Достаточно одной искры, чтобы все пошло наперекосяк.

Here I wanted to express the idea of "a tinderbox situation waiting to ignite" or "a powder-keg situation waiting to explode". What is a commonly used phrasing for this?

Comment: in the 2nd sentence you have combined idioms which don't really sit well with one another and because of that create a somewhat comic effect, the 2nd part is expected to follow from the 1st one, namely to be about fire or explosives

Comment: i personally would need more context to come up with an apt phrase

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка We were talking about  two warring political factions.

Comment: still more context is welcome... but working with what's available i could offer **чтобы начались столкновения** if violence is looming, or **чтобы разразился политический кризис/наступил кризис власти**, basically similar to what Dmitriy has suggested, something more straightforward than a concatenation of idioms

Comment: and then also **Достаточно одной искры, чтобы произошёл** ***политический*** **взрыв** or **... на грани. Любое неосторожное слово/Любой необдуманный шаг может переполнить чашу терпения/оказаться последней каплей**, but this is just a matter of creative use of language

Comment: В литературе вполне употребимо прямое сравнение ситуации с пороховой бочкой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тогда уже **"чтобы всё пошло под откос"**, это про поезд на взорванных путях. :) А то наперекосяк - не настолько опасно.

> **Сидеть на пороховой бочке.** Сейчас все как на пороховой бочке.
>
> **Быть на волосок от гибели/краха/чего-то ещё.** Стороны на волосок от конфликта.
>
> **Висеть на волоске.** Судьба/мир висит на волоске.
>
> **Быть на взводе.** *На взводе бывает курок огнестрельного оружия, и так
>   же говорят про нервы при напряженной обстановке.* Обе стороны на взводе, и лучше не подливать масла в огонь.
>
> **Подливать масло в огонь.**
>
> **Только спичку брось.** Обстановка такая, что только спичку брось.

И т.д., и т.п.

Comment: "Взрывоопасная ситуация" should probably be at the 1st or 2nd position along with "Сидеть на пороховой бочке".

Answer (score 2):

Two phrases that you use ("Обе стороны на грани", "Достаточно одной искры") already express the idea of "a tinderbox situation waiting to ignite". There are some others, for example: "взрывоопасная ситуация", "обстановка накаляется (or накалилась)". What you need, as [@Баян Купи-ка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/7674/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD-%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0) said, is to remove the third expression and add some neutral explanation, what can happen. For example:

> Обе стороны на грани. Достаточно одной искры, чтобы началась потасовка.

I suppose, "стороны" here are two groups of people. Two gangs, for example. Or, in the case of armies:

> Обе стороны на грани. Достаточно одной искры, чтобы начались боевые действия.

Or you can say "Обстановка накалилась" instead of "Обе стороны на грани".

Answer (score 0):

In historical or diplomatic documents, or in the press, they oftentimes say  "конфронтация дошла *до опасной черты*".

A less formal version is: "конфронтация дошла *до предела*" .